How to get dictionary words and alternatives using API
I want to implement a dictionary/alternative section for the selected word in the source input text area.
In DeepL site, there is a way to change the word with alternative word provided by DeepL and also option to see dictionary. something like below
DeepL Dictionary and Alternative option
I don't find any API for it. Is it possible?

The "alternatives" feature from the deepl.com web translator (giving alternative translations to the most likely one, e.g. a different tone, or to distinguish synonyms in the source language) is not exposed via the DeepL API.

On deepl.com, if you translate something, in addition to a most likely translation it will also offer alternative translations (e.g. a different tone, or to distinguish synonyms in the source language). You can also select words and receive alternatives for that word/phrase specifically. This feature is however not available via API.

Thank you, Gaze, for the information. I would like to inquire if there are any upcoming plans to release APIs for dictionary services and their alternatives.
